# Labelmg crashes every time

Tags: python, github, terminal, pip, labelimg

if I used to start to draw a react in labelIMG it crahes all the time.

This here is the log from the terminal:

```
2023-09-29 12:24:13.167 Python[78234:1304928] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-09-29 12:24:13.481 Python[78234:1304928] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/hope/labelImg/libs/canvas.py", line 485, in paintEvent
    p.drawLine(self.prevPoint.x(), 0, self.prevPoint.x(), self.pixmap.height())
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  drawLine(self, QLineF): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, QLine): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, int, int, int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, QPoint, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, Union[QPointF, QPoint], Union[QPointF, QPoint]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
Abort trap: 6
```

I started the program with the command: pipenv --python=3.9 run python3 labelImg.py

This is my python Version:

```
python3 -V
Python 3.9.6
```